# Why do python's different forms for import behave differently for circular imports?

Tags: python

I'm creating a python 2.7 library with the following directory structure:

```
$ pwd
~/code/myproject
$ tree
.
|- myproject
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- exception.py
|   |-- myproject.py
```

Here are the contents of the three files:

```
$ cat __init__.py
import myproject
$ cat myproject.py
from . import exception
$ cat exception.py
from . import myproject
```

When I import this new library from a second project, an exception in raised:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  <snip>
  File "~/code/myproject/myproject/exception.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import myproject
ImportError: cannot import name myproject
```

I understand that the fix is to change the contents of exception.py to:

```
import myproject
```

... but I don't know why. All the best practices seem to recommend using relative imports for files in a package. Why does the import behaviour change when exception.py changes from `from . import myproject` to `import myproject`?

Comment: That's an obvious circular import. You should refactor to avoid the cycle...

Comment: *"All the best practices seem to recommend using relative imports for files in a package."* -- {citation needed}

Comment: As nneonneo says, the problem isn't so much the name as the circularity of the import.  If `myproject.py` did not try to import `exception`, then the import in `exception` would work fine.

Comment: OK, can you explain it like I'm 5? Why does it work when exception.py is just `import project` but not when it's `from . import myproject`

Comment: Just to rule out a misleading problem, verify the value of `myproject.__file__` after the successful import.  It's possible you are importing a different package that has the same name as your local project but is located elsewhere on the Python path.

Comment: Good idea, @ChrisJohnson. In an ipython shell from the project's root directory, I ran `import myproject`. From the ipython shell, `myproject.__file__ == 'myproject/__init__.py'`, which I expect. Within exception.py, `myproject.__file__ == 'myproject/myproject.py'`. `exception.py` can access symbols defined in `myproject.py`, but not from `__init__.py`.